# Iteration with while loop - python

Tags: python

When I, for exmaple, chose 1, the code "do something" but then it doesn't repeat the menu again. Instead, it displayes "1". Why? And How can I solve that?

```
menu = input('1. \n 2. \n')


choice = input(menu)


while choice in ['1', '2']:

   print(input(menu))

   if choice == 1:
      #do something

   elif choice == 2:
      #do something

   else:
      break
```

Comment: you have `while choice in ['1', '2']: ...` For that condition to ever be `True`, `choice` would have to be a string.  However, inside the body of the loop you're comparing `choice == 1` which is comparing choice to an integer so it will _never_ execute ...

Comment: its better to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. so you should use `int(raw_input(something here))`.

Comment: Multiple problems:
* You call input all over the place, let menu be a string and then call menu() when you want the input
* In the while statement you compare to strings but input runns eval on the input so you get an int

Comment: `print(input(menu))` - WTF? It seems so pointless...

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing `string` with `int`
your choice is `type int`, as input default take as `string`

Demo:

```
>>>'1' == 1
False
```

try like this:

```
def take_input():
    menu = input('1. \n 2. \n')
    return menu
menu = take_input()
while menu in ['1', '2']:
   if menu == '1':
      #do something
      menu = take_input()          
   elif menu == '2':
      #do something
      menu = take_input()
   else:
      break
```

you can remove that unwanted `while menu in ['1','2']`

```
while True:
    menu= take_input()
    if menu == '1':
        #do something
        menu= take_input()
    elif menu=='2':
        #do something
        menu= take_input()
    else:break
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go. I'm not sure why you doing this `choice = input(menu)` I replaced it. I have put `break` to stop the execution because it would go to infinite loop. You want it to go to infinite then remove the `break`.Also the `else` part inside `while` will never be executed as you are checking if `choice` is either "1" or "2".

```
def display_menu():
    menu = input('1. \n 2. \n')
    return str(menu)

def get_choice():
    choice = display_menu()
    while choice in ['1', '2']:
        if choice == "1":
           print "inside if condition"
           get_choice()

        elif choice == "2":
           print "inside elif condition"
          #do something
           get_choice()
        else:
           print "inside else condtion"
           break

get_choice()
```

Comment: OP  want to break only `input` is other than 1 or 2

Comment: But I need to display the menu each time. Like if the user entered 1, then the program will do something and then it will display the menu again.

Comment: @Hackaholic If input is other than 1 or 2 then in won't even enter the `while` loop at all. If it's 1 or 2 then it goes to infinite loop so I have put `break`

Comment: @GameDesigner Then you should wrap in functions. I have made edits accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Put the menu in the loop, and change the strings to ints, like this:

```
menu = 'Type 1 or 2: '
choice = input(menu)
while choice in [1, 2]:
    if choice == 1: print 11111
    elif choice == 2: print 22222
    choice = input(menu)
```